# Extracting text+variable from file not workng

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I have a lot of files constantly (more than 1500 per day) that i have to search for "\HF=" which then have a value
example

```
\HF=-546.523456
```

This is almost never the same value and most of the time negative values.

The problem here is that the "\HF" appears near the bottom of the file but it could appear separeted in two consecutives lines, like this:

```
bla bla bla \H
F=number
```

or

```
bla bla bla \
HF=number
```

I google a LOT and mixing a lot of this reading I got to this:

```
grep "\\\\HF=[-]\?[0-9]*[.]\?[0-9]*\\\\" *.log
```

(these are .log files)

The `grep` command doesn't work when I don't get the exact "\HF"; I don't know why but `-r` doesn't work either, and I have a lot of subdirectories.

Can you help me creating a bash script?

Here is an example of the bottom of the file

```
 -1.8078238555,2.9578874797\H,-6.5637417591,1.9616010611,-0.4401499738\
 H,-6.788515386,1.1005867152,1.097842586\H,-6.6310211349,0.1875790572,-
 0.4056194057\\Version=EM64L-G09RevB.01\State=1-A\HF=-2032.6976718\RMSD
 =5.982e-09\RMSF=5.561e-07\Dipole=3.5537566,0.6605675,0.6605341\Quadrup
 ole=-5.9562335,7.5807637,-1.6245302,-27.037518,-2.3011825,2.5397027\PG
 =C01 [X(C37H33B1O8)]\\@


 THE WORLD IS MADE UP OF THE WILLS, THE WON'TS, AND THE CANT'S:
 THE WILLS DO EVERYTHING,
 THE WON'TS DO NOTHING,
 THE CAN'TS CAN'T DO ANYTHING.

                               -- FROM WALT DISNEY'S "BLACK HOLE"
 Job cpu time:  1 days  5 hours 59 minutes 54.7 seconds.
 File lengths (MBytes):  RWF=   2510 Int=      0 D2E=      0 Chk=     20 Scr=      1
 Normal termination of Gaussian 09 at Mon Dec 24 19:58:22 2012.
```

Comment: Does the `H` actually matter here? Could you simply looks for `F=-?\d+(\.\d+)?`?

Comment: yes it is, there are more than 300K lines and actually adding the \ to the HF makes it different from a lot of other HF= from the text.

Comment: how many times will the \HF be in your file? only once?

Comment: yes, sorry, i've miss your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first things first, the flag you want is `-R`, to recursively `grep` through the directories.

Secondly, since you know the information you want is by the end of the file, grab enough lines  for you to be sure the information will be there, remove the line breaks, and do the simple search.

You may do the following:

```
tail -30 <file> | sed "s/^ *\(.*\) *$/\1/" |
    tr -d "\n" | grep -oP "\\\\HF=[-]?\d+\.\d+"
```

Since you have to do this recursively, you may use `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.log' -print0 |
    xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'tail -30 "{}" | sed "s/^ *\(.*\) *$/\1/" |
        tr -d "\n" | grep --label "{}" -oHP "\\\\HF=[-]?\d+\.\d{1,4}"'
```

If the number may not contain decimals, you can change the expression to:

```
... grep --label "{}" -oHP "\\\\HF=[-]?\d+(\.\d{1,4})?"
```

With the file "temp.log":

```
bla bla bla \
HF=-546.523456
something else but a number
bla bla bla \
HF=-546.523456
something else but a number
```

The output is:

```
./temp.log:\HF=-546.523456
./temp.log:\HF=-546.523456
```

Comment: @user1997194 It should be working fine now; please, try it and check if there's anything wrong. It's now also able to traverse directories and files with spaces in the name.

Comment: ive tried it and ive got only three results, i add the bottom of a file which is not found. Besides it founds me in two subdirectories but not in the main (maybe the same cause which it finds too little results). I really appreciate the time and effort you are putting on helping me

Comment: i think you've got it! =D now i'm going to check that no result is missing, but at least this time i've got 22 results. One question, some results have more number next to the . can that be fixed? these results include the ones where \, H, F & = may be in different lines? like \H F= or \ HF or even \HF =?? thank you sooo much!

Comment: @user1997194 Would you mind to add an example in which the output seems strange, as you defined? I didn't really get the idea from *some results have more number next to the . *.

Comment: yes, what i meant was that some results were ie ./casa/TSR_Si_OMe_C12a_pt3_opt3.log:\HF=-2032.6823
./casa/TSS_Si_OMe_C32a_optB.log:\HF=-2056.54
./casa/TSS_Re_OMe_C54_opt3.log:\HF=-2032.6887419

Comment: It is almost right, except for the amount of numbers after the period

Comment: could the numbers of decimals be defined with a \. I meant, the number to be found is like this "\HF=number.decimal\" the \ mark the end of the number

Comment: one other thing, where can i modify to put the location where i want this to be executed, so i add it to another script which must run from a different location? Thank you SO MUCH for all your help

Comment: @user1997194 You just have to change the vaalue inside the curly brackets. I guess you're using the script the have `...{1,4}`. Change these values to the range you want -- if you have from 7 to 10 decimal numbers, use `...{7,10}`.

Comment: Rubens, here is the link to a file which is giving me problems. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fh0i9dl5dnpbgvm/TS_Aldol_C14_opt3.log  If you open the file and go to the bottom or just search on file for the \HF you would find the number -1067.4 which continues on the next sentence with 811814. I need to obtain the number -1067.4811814 on the script result. Hope this file helps getting there. Thanks again

Comment: @user1997194 Hi, I had to finish some couple of things, and they took me sometime ^^ Here's the solution for what you want: `tail -30 TS_Aldol_C14_opt3.log | sed 's/^ *\(.*\) *$/\1/' | tr -d "\n" | grep --label "your_file" -oHP "\\\\HF=[-]?\d+\.\d+"`. Hope it works fine now! The `| sed ... |` step is to take off leading and trailing spaces, so that simply removing the `\n` later, with `tr`, will join the digits.

Comment: wow that was quick! i will try it and see what happens. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user1997194 You're welcome! I'm online if you it pops out any problem. I guess we could remove some couple of comments from here, just to clean up the post. I'll remove some, and you remove those that you posted.